# Create a method to print child arrayList items in java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have an abstract `Person` class which has 3 children: `Admin`, `Employee` and `Student`. There is only one admin object.

I also have a class which it's "name" is `Statics` and holds all public data I need, like this:

```
public class Statics {  

private static Person currentLoginUser;
private static ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
//We don't need ArrayList<Admin> because there is only one admin in the whole program

//Adder and getter methods:
//...
}
```

You may ask what `ArrayList<Person>` in the code is? When I create an object, I add it to both "it's own type arraylist" and "`ArrayList<Person>`". So `ArrayList<Person>` has everybody.

As I said, I only have 1 admin:

```
Person admin = new Admin(); //`Admin` extends `Person`
```

I want to create a method (in `Admin` class) which takes an arrayList of `Person` as input and prints it's data. So I did this:

```
//Admin class:
public void printList(ArrayList<Person> people){
//Do something
}
```

Let's assume `admin` wants to see the list of the students: I call it like this:

```
ArrayList<Student> s = Statics.getStudents();
((Admin)admin).printList(s); //admin object was created by `Person` class so I have to cast it to (Admin) to use `Admin`'s own methods.
```

It (eclipse) says that:

> The method printList(ArrayList<`Person`>) in the type Admin is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<`Student`>)

I tried to cast it to person:

```
((Admin)admin).printList((ArrayList<Person>)s);
```

this time I got this error:

> Cannot cast from ArrayList<`Student`> to ArrayList<`Person`>

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175918/java-how-to-i-get-values-inside-arraylist-when-theres-parent-child-involved) the answer is to pass the main arrayList and check if it's object's are from type "Student" or not, then print it's value but I don't want to check the whole `Person` arrayList everytime! I just want a method, which takes and arrayList of `Person`'s children (`Employee`, `Student`, etc) and prints them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `printList` method signature to:

```java
public void printList(ArrayList<? extends Person> people)
```

**Explanation**:

Changing the signature will allow you to pass an `ArrayList` parameterized with `Person` or its subclasses.

In java the `? extends T` construct is known as [Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html).

When using the `people` inside the `printList` method you will be able to "consume" (`get`) people from the list (but not to "produce" (`add`) them). "Consume" and "produce" are meant here in the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) sense.

---

For more information about generics see [Generics (Java tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with generics. Even though `Student` extends `Person`, `List<Student>` does **not** extend `List<Person>`. That's why java generics has the *wildcard* which is represented with a `?` (question mark).

If you use `List<? extends Person>` that means that each element in the list is an instance of either `Person` or any class that extends `Person`.

Refer to [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) in the *Generics* lesson of the *Learning the Java Language* trail in Oracle's java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Abra problem is with generics.
You can use generics in your code to fix your problem.

Create `Admin` class as a generic class and create `printList` method with 
`List<T> list` argument so that it will accept any type of object. e.g Person, Employee, Student etc.

This is just an example so please change your code accordingly.

```
public class Admin<T> {

  public void printList(List<T> list) {
   // Print list here
  }
}
```

```
    Statics stat = new Statics();
    Admin admin = new Admin<Student>();

    // Students
    admin.printList(stat.getStudents());
    // Employees
    admin.printList(stat.getEmployees());
    // People
    admin.printList(stat.getPeople());
```

Comment: Why admin is a generic type? I didn't get that part.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Yeahh it is required to be generic otherwise you will get an error  **The type Admin is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Student>**